# Javascript RegEx working in chrome and IE but not in firefox

Tags: javascript, regex, backbone.js

I want to write a javascript regex to allow negative float numbers.I have written following regEx

```
value.match(/^\-?[0-9]{0,4}(.[0-9]{1,4})?/g);
```

which works fin for chrome and IE for keypress event but not in firefox.And everything works fine in all browsers on blur event.Can any one help me?

Comment: Do you have a fiddle? Also, you might want to escape the dot:  `value.match(/^\-?[0-9]{0,4}(\.[0-9]{1,4})?/g);`

Comment: @Tetaxa no i don't have fiddle.Sorry.Will make it and post link here

Comment: This might sound a stupid question, but exactly what key you're listening with `onkeypress`?

Comment: @Teemu Any character except function keys obviously

Comment: Why not use `parseFloat` and check against `isNaN`/`x<0`?

Comment: That is highly unlikely. Are you sure the _value_ is same in both browsers?

Comment: @SalmanA yes i have debugged the code in all three browsers

Comment: What is `\-`? Do you mean `-?` or `\\-?`?

Comment: \- is escape sequence for - I guess

Comment: No, it's not. `-` has no special meaning (outside of a character class), it does not have to be escaped.

Comment: @nikhilmehta Well, keys producing non-printable characters are firing a keypress event in FF only ...